# Why should not be two collection interfaces be implemented together?

Tags: java, collections, interface

I know what an interface is and what is a collection. But to be honest, I could not find any solid reason as why not to implement two collection interfaces in one class.

Got this question asked a few days back in an interview.

Comment: If nothing else, it creates a confusing API. What does it mean for something to be both a List and a Map? In most cases (not all, but most), it'll be clearer if you have your class _contain_ both a List and a Map, with appropriate methods get get at those instances. This is called composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases they are or can be implemented by the same object.

A Queue and a List are both implemented by LinkedList, TreeMap is both NavigableMap and SortedMap.  There are a few other examples like this.

Each describes a trait or feature of the collection (exposed as a way to use it).

It just doesn't make sense all that often. For a Java collection to implement two interfaces it must be a near perfect implementation of both (and perhaps that's your answer).

A linkedlist COULD technically implement the methods of an ArrayList, however it would be a really bad idea.

Comment: Plus one for being the first to point out that standard java actually does this.

Comment: If standard Java already does it, then why is it, that it should not be used? Should depend on the design really. I guess so

Comment: @PritamBanerjee it really depends which collection interfaces you're talking about.  `Queue` and `List` are intercompatible, but I'm not sure there are any other pairs that are.

Comment: I don't know why they would say that.  Some interview questions are confrontational to cause discussion without actually having "Correct" answers.  Sometimes it's best to simply feel comfortable and consider it a discussion starter rather then a question.

Comment: Also, note `HashSet` _has-a_ `HashMap` internally; it isn't actually a `HashMap` and you can't cast it to one.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I believe you are right--the hash set thing wasn't an interface thing--it was that a hash set internally used a hashmap as it's implementation.  will remove from answer.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, incompatible method contracts: e.g. `List.add` must always return `true`, and `Set.add` must always return `false` if the element is already present.

Comment: I guess you could have an *immutable* `ListSet` as the methods that mutate are allowed to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington, `add` isn't the only method with an incompatible contract.  `equals` and `hashCode` also have incompatible contracts, and making your collections immutable won't help you reconcile that difference.

Answer (score 1):

Another point that hasn't been made already is that you can't implement the same interface twice with different type parameters.

As a result, if you tried to make a class implement both `List<String>` and `Collection<Integer>`, you would get a compiler error. This is because `List<String>` extends `Collection<String>` so we're trying to implement `Collection` twice with different type parameters.

If you did manage to implement two collection interfaces at once, it would have to be like the `LinkedList` example (where the generic type is the same when you think of it as a `List` and when you think of it as a `Deque`).